# Django 2 media returns error 404 (top level media folder)

Tags: django, django-2.1

Running Django 2.1.5 with Python 3.7.2 32-bit, Win10 localhost, no nginx etc. Cloned the repo https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example.git

Can upload files and they appear as a url link in the db and as a list item on the page but the images/files do not display on the page and return 404 in the console.

Error returned:
`GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/documents/2019/04/07/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)`
I can see the file at that location in explorer.

The code is exactly as per the repo with the addition of the following:

list.html line 14

```
<li><img src="{{ document.docfile.url }}" height="60px"></li>
```

and

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [ path('', views.list, name='list')]
```

I have followed the documentation as far as I can and looked at other SO post that suggest the static pattern should go first.

It should be noted that the media folder is at the top level of the directory.

for_django_2-0

-myproject

--myproject

--media

--myapp

Also:
`DEBUG = True`
Have tried running with:
`python manage.py runserver 8001 --insecure`
and
`python manage.py runserver 8001`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, after some more digging on another topic I found this useful video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIvlcmnayOE&t=55s

The video explains something I missed in the other tutorials.  Your static urls path needs to be in the root project urls.py not the app urls.py

myproject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns =  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls'))
```

This now works.